# Getting the module size

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, module

Is there a way to get the size of a loaded module in c++ considering that I have the base DLL address?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call [GetModuleInformation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683201(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: ... and look into the `SizeOfImage` member of the `MODULEINFO` structure. `</captainobvious>` `:)`